# Check if point is in triangle ($n$-dimensional case for any $n\ge 2$)

Tags: geometry

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be points in $\mathbb R^n$  that are not collinear. Let

$$I=\{X:X=A+\lambda\overrightarrow{AB}+\mu\overrightarrow{AC} \text{ where } \lambda,\mu,\lambda+\mu\in[0,1]\}.$$

(So, $I$ is the interior of the triangle, including the line segments).

Let $P$ be a point. How do we check whether $P\in I$?

This is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51326/determining-if-an-arbitrary-point-lies-inside-a-triangle-defined-by-three-points) but that was for the two- or three-dimensional case only. (And I believe all of the answers there were only for those cases.)

Comment: Just solve the obvious system for $\lambda,\ \mu.$ If no solution P not even in the plane of triangle. Uf there is, finish by checking if resulting $\lambda,\ \mu$ satisfy your stated constraints.